# Server performance issue

Tags: 14.04, server, games

I have an issue with a server I am hosting a game on.
Now, this server is basically dedicated to this game, with a MySQL server and the game itself running on there. I keep getting reports that the game is lagging during certain functions.
I have narrowed the time down to the following:

[image: screenshot]

When there is 2Gb~ of free memory, there are no problems. But when it dwindles towards 0... Thats when I have problems. I have looked at the processes running using `top` and I cant see anything that is eating more than a few percentage point of the memory.

I am new to Linux, and servers in general, can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Screenshot of my `top` screen 
[image: top while at normal use]

EDIT: Added another screencap of my top readout. This is what it looks like when things go haywire. I can account for 25%~ of the memory... but the other 75% is just gone for some reason. Can someone please tell me how to find what is using it?

[image: top readout]

Comment: Anyone able to explain where this memory is being used at?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you need to do at an absolute minimum is to add more RAM.  Games work best when they have someplace to live while they're running, and the swop space on the hard drive is a few magnitudes too slow.

I'd go out and buy 16GB of RAM, and throw it in there.  That would solve that problem.

If you don't want to just upgrade RAM, you could disable other memory intensive processes, like the GUI if you have it.  Also, the MySQL server could be taking up a good bit of memory.

Comment: Ill add a screenshot of my `top` so you can see that there shouldnt be anything using that memory (that I can see)

Comment: Yes please do so.

Comment: OK, so it looks like your game is the one using the majority of memory.  You really can't get away with lack of RAM in a game.  I assume it's minecraft?

Comment: Modded minecraft can use as much as 12GB or more of memory.

Comment: So I'd upgrade it to 16GB or more if you can

Comment: I have it set to use only 6 of the 8GB and it often works fine. But something is sucking those remaining two gigs up and leave the node wanting... That what you can see with the graph.

Comment: Yes it is MC, and the game itself, runs fine, It internally uses about 30 - 50% of the 6Gb allocated... But once the system memory is gone, the node starves and processing anything takes forever.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to get some more RAM.

Comment: That doesnt explain anything...
Just throwing more ram doesnt explain why the unallocated memory is being used by... seemingly nothing...

Comment: Linux (or any OS for that matter) has certain functions that need performing, and that must run period.  Run top while you're running out of memory, and then see what's doing it.

Comment: I get that, but `top` should tell me what is using it. The screenshot I posted above shows what it looks like. Even when the game instance is using 100% allocated memory... I should still have 4Gb of system memory free. But I dont and I have no Idea where it goes.